# grep minus number doesn't work

Tags: grep

I want to find all files in a directory which contains `-2`.

Using `ls | grep "-2"` returns `usage: grep...`

Using single quotes instead of double quotes returns the same, and also not using quotes at all, while searching for anything else correctly returns matching filenames.

As I remember `-` is not a regex special character.

Please don't focus on the specific problem of finding files with a name.
I primarily want to understand why grep is behaving this way.

Using bash on macOS 10.13

Comment: I agree. Strange. No clue. But `ls | grep -e "-2"` will work. Just tell grep it is an expression. Seems the dash is read as an option. Must be the piping.

Comment: Thanks. It is like if it is interpreting `-2` as a command line parameter, regardless the fact it is wrapped by quotes.

Comment: Use: `grep -- -2` or `grep -- "-2"`

Comment: [How to use grep to search for a pattern which starts with a hyphen (-)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/500957/253474), [How can I grep for a string that begins with a dash/hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427913/995714), [Match with grep when pattern is in variable and contains hyphen “-”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388892/44425), [grep getting confused by filenames with dashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364922/44425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is like if it is interpreting -2 as a command line parameter, regardless the fact it is wrapped by quotes.

`grep` *does not know* whether a parameter is wrapped by quotes or not.

Many parsing steps are performed by the shell itself<sup>1</sup> before executing anything at all – `>` redirections are applied, `$` variables are expanded, `*` wildcards are expanded, `|` pipelines split into a set of individual commands, and each command split into an array of words.

So whether you run `grep -2`, `grep '-2'`, `grep \-2`, or even `x=-2; grep $x`, the shell still sees it as the same list of parameters: {`grep`, `-2`}. This is what will be passed to the execv() system call, and it is what the *grep* program will receive in its `argv[]` array, regardless of the original quoting.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even on Windows, where the command line in CreateProcess() is just a single string, most ports of *grep* will still have this behavior because the C runtime library performs the same arg-splitting during initialization.

Comment: so `-e` will pass `{ grep, "-2" }`? as this works like mentioned in my comment to the OP

Comment: No. It will pass `{ grep, -e, -2 }`. But grep knows that `-e` takes exactly one parameter, so the following `-2` will be consumed as the -e parameter rather than a standalone option.